# android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/FileNmae exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function for opening a file when the downloading is completed:

```
fun openDownloadedFile(context: Context?, fileName: String) {
    val storageDirectory =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + STORAGE_DIRECTORY + "/${fileName}"
    val file = File(storageDirectory)

    if (file.exists()) {
        val downloadedFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
        val fileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        fileIntent.setDataAndType(downloadedFileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
        fileIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        
        context?.startActivity(fileIntent)
    }
}
```

I have also declared a file provider in manifest.xml file

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="net.mytvplus.stbstore.file_provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider" />
</provider>
```

file_provider.xml:

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

When the downlaoding is completed, the application crashes and I get this message in logcat:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException:
> file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/FileNmae exposed beyond app
> through Intent.getData()

Any help?

Comment: You are not using FileProvider to get an uri for your file.

Comment: And already with Android 7/N people encountered this exception. Where have you been? Why did t you google?

Comment: I read many answers but I didn't see any difference in my code and the correct one, I didn't realize that the implementation of FileProvider was  missing

Comment: Do not use Uri.fromFile(). Use FileProvider.getUriForFile() to get a suitable uri.